# MongoDB Aggregation - Fetch data from ObjectId subarray

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have these collections:

author

```
[
  {
    _id: "63c242130b17d5516e0cb499",
    author_name:'Vyom',
    book_ids:["63c242330b17d5516e0cb49a","63c242410b17d5516e0cb49b"]
  }
]
```

book

```
[
  {
    _id:"63c242330b17d5516e0cb49a",
    author_id:'63c242130b17d5516e0cb499',
    book_name:'True Love',
    genere:'horror'
  },
  {
    _id:"63c242410b17d5516e0cb49b",
    author_id:'63c242130b17d5516e0cb499',
    book_name:'Monster Strike',
    genere:'romance'
  },
]
```

I want to fetch details of books in author collection aggregation if `book_ids` exists.

For this I tried as:

```
db.author.aggregate([
     {
       $match: {
         _id: ObjectId("63c242130b17d5516e0cb499")
       }
     },
     {
       $lookup:{
         from: 'book',
         localField: '_id',
         foreignField: 'author_id',
         as: 'book_details'
       }
     },
     {
        $addFields:{
           book_info: {
             $map: {
              input: '$book_details'
              as: 'el'
              in: {
                  $match: {_id:ObjectId('$$el._id')},
                  $paroject: {book_name: 1},
              }
             }
           }
        }                   
     }
])
```

But it throws:

> Unrecognized error: '$match'.

Expected O/P:

```
[
  {
    _id: "63c242130b17d5516e0cb499",
    author_name:'Vyom',
    book_ids:["63c242330b17d5516e0cb49a","63c242410b17d5516e0cb49b"],
    book_info: [
      {
        _id:"63c242330b17d5516e0cb49a",
        book_name:'True Love',
      },
      {
        _id:"63c242410b17d5516e0cb49b",
        book_name:'Monster Strike',
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any other way to loop and get details? I tried looking for other solutions but was unable to find.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a `$set` stage to format the element in the `book_details` array for the `book_info` field.

You can use [`$lookup` with pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax) to join both collections and format the array of documents returned.

```
db.author.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("63c242130b17d5516e0cb499")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "book",
      localField: "book_ids",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "book_info",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            book_name: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Cmuy6HJaWK)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.authors.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "books",
            localField: "book_ids",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "books"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "books": { $ne: [] } }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            author_name: 1,
            books: {
                _id: 1,
                author_id: 1,
                book_name: 1,
                genre: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This pipeline will give you the result where all the authors' book details will be there if they have any books